# Expected value of a prize that has a geometric distribution dependent on independent draws from a uniform distribution.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

A number $X$ and a sequence of numbers $\{Y_n\vert n\in \mathbb N\}$ are i.i.d draws from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Let $N = \inf\{n \in \mathbb N\vert Y_n > X\}$. The player conducting these draws receives the prize of $(N - 1)$. Calculate the expected value of this prize.

I understand that $(N-1)/X= x \sim Geometric(1 - X)$ but I do not know how to proceed further.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please update your question to include your thoughts on the problem, and where you are getting stuck exactly. We will be happy to guide you further.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Observe that: $$\{N=n\}=\{Y_n>X\geq\max(Y_1,\dots,Y_{n-1})\}$$

concerning the order of $n+1$ iid and continuous random variables.

The orders for $X,Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ are equiprobable and there are $(n+1)!$ orders.

Further there are $(n-1)!$ orders that satisfy the condition $Y_n>X>\max(Y_1,\dots,Y_{n-1})$ leading to: $$P(N=n)=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n+1)!}=\frac1{n(n+1)}$$

Comment: Even simpler: $\{N>n\}=\{X>\max\{Y_1,\ldots,Y_n\}\}$. By the [exchangeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables#Definition) of the sample $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n,X)$, the probability of this event is $\frac1{n+1}$, end of proof.